# Issue with registration function using email template layout - cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

A strange one to be honest.  I have got this working completely fine on my local machine but on the production server (CENTOS), the redirect after registering is hitting the email template..

Is there something I am missing here?

```
  function register() {
        $this->layout = 'login';
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Register');
        if(!empty($this->data)) {
                  $this->User->create();
                     if($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                        $this->data['User']['group_id'] = 4;
                        $this->_sendNewUserMail( $this->User->id );
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'approval'));
                    } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('There were errors found in your registration.  Please check the highlighted fields', true));
                }
        }               
    }

    function _sendNewUserMail($id) {
        $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
                            'port'=>'25', 
                            'timeout'=>'30',
                            'host' => 'localhost',
                            'username'=>'username',
                            'password'=>'password',
        );
        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
        $User = $this->User->read(null,$id);
        $this->Email->to = array('someone@blah.com');
        $this->Email->subject = 'A new registration has been submitted';
        $this->Email->from = 'Me@blah.com';
        $this->Email->template = 'default';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
        $this->set('User', $User);
        $this->Email->send();
    }
```

I am completely stumped with this..

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: in production it sends the mail?

Comment: @pleasedontbelong Unfortunately it's not sending any mail on the production server - seems to indicate that there is something missing in the php config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess php_openssl is not enabled. Also, you should move the smtpOptions and delivery setting into _sendNewUserMail

Comment: I have removed the gmail settings (was only used for testing on the local machine) and now using localhost for smtp relay on the production server and registration is still be redirected to the email template as apposed to approval. The things is, I don't have this php_openssl module present in my local php.ini and ssl://smtp.gmail.com works fine.

Answer (score 1):

[From the comments]

It seems that there was an error in the production server (maybe due to a different configuration in the SMTP server) I assume that in your production server you have the debug set to 0. So the errors are not displayed, That's why instead of redirecting, it renders the email template.

You'll need to debug the smtp errors in production. To do that, you could add:

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

in the action/controller that sends the email, so you'd be able to see the error. Also, you could check the smtp errors in the `$this->Email->smtpError` variable.

That way you'll be able to see what's wrong. I don't know much about smtp server's configurations so that might be another S.O. question.

Hope this helps